# Relationship extraction from text using python

Tags: python, classification, nltk, relation

I have a set of Complaints coming in a text file. Each of the complaints have a mention of the faulty component, the position of the component of the problem with the component.
Need to scan each of the complaint & automatically be able to list out the position, component & the problem. How can this be done in python?
for eg:
the complaint: "The right door ddoesnt open"
so the o/p should be : Position: right, Component:door, Problem: doesnt open.

Tried custom tagging but after that wasnt able to extract relationships

Comment: Could you give a more complete example?

Comment: This is going to be very difficult unless the incoming text file has some structure to it that highlights the position, component and problem. If the data comes as sentences (like your example) then you are getting into the realm of Natural Language Processing, which is far from straightforward.

Comment: Provide a large list of examples and then one can get a rough idea how complex it will get…

Comment: example:Customer FEELS STEERING IS TOO HARD,SO CUS IS NOT SATISFIED.
Customer says that after servicing the brakes are not working properly, and hence it is a repeated concern.